# Pi4 enable uart4 without using boot/config.txt

Tags: pi-4, uart

I need to be able to enable uart4 on a Pi4 using dtoverlay, without adding it to /boot/config.txt, and have /dev/ttyAMA2 available immediately. The dtoverlay part is easy, `sudo dtoverlay uart4`, but /dev/ttyAMA2 does not show up.

Why? Because I am setting up automated configuration of a device and while I'm writing `dtoverlay=uart4` to /boot/config.txt, I need to be able to immediately access that serial port without a reboot, in order to flash firmware to a device on that port.

`dtoverlay -l` shows the overlay. I just don't understand how to get /dev/ttyAMA2 to show up as a device.

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have the same need...

Answer (score 1):

When you add an overlay using the dtoverlay command, it only applies to the current running session. It does not persist across reboots, so it won't be available immediately after a reboot.

To make the overlay persistent, you need to add it to the /boot/config.txt file. However, if you don't want to modify that file, you can create a temporary overlay file that includes your desired overlay and then load it using the dtoverlay command. Here's how you can do it:

Create a new file with your overlay configuration. For example, you can create a file named uart4-overlay.dts with the following contents:

```
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

/ {
  fragment@0 {
    target = <&uart4>;
    __overlay__ {
      status = "okay";
    };
  };
};
```

Compile the overlay file by running this command:

```
dtc -@ -I dts -O dtb -o uart4.dtbo uart4-overlay.dts
```

Load the overlay using the dtoverlay command:
sudo dtoverlay uart4.dtbo
After running these commands, /dev/ttyAMA2 should become available as a device.

Comment: Thank you. How is this different from the overlays that already exist, such as "uart4"?

Answer (score 0):

It is far from clear WHY you don't want to use config.txt.

You can enable a dtoverlay on the fly with the following command:-

```
sudo dtoverlay uart4
```

You will need to repeat this every time you boot.

The serial port will be assigned the next available /dev/ttyAMA
This will normally be `/dev/ttyAMA1`

See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/107780/8697

Comment: I explained why, despite its lack of relevance to the answer. The intent is for it to be tamporary. I also explained that when using  `sudo dtoverlay uart4`, /dev/ttyAMA2 does not show up.

Comment: When I tested this in 2020 it worked I tried on Raspberry Pi OS Bullseye and dtoverlay did not work. Something must have changed.